# How to sum numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sum, numbers

Hi i have a table in which i want in the first cell of second row "a2" to show me the total of selected number from the dropdown + the number from first row "a1". How can i do that? For now i've made it to show me the number chosen from the dropdown. Also how to make it sum the number digit by digit and show the total?

```js
function myFunction() {
    var month = document.getElementById("drop");
    document.getElementById("a2").innerHTML = drop.options[drop.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th, tr{
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form>
  Number:
  <select id="drop" onchange ="myFunction()">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
    <option>13</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
<table>
    <tr>
  <tr>
    <th id="a1">1</th>
    <th id="b1">2</th>
    <th id="c1">3</th>
    <th id="d1">4</th>
    <th id="e1">5</th>
    <th id="f1">6</th>
    <th id="g1">7</th>
    <th id="h1">8</th>
    <th id="i1">9</th>
    <th id="j1">10</th>
    <th id="k1">11</th>
    <th id="l1">12</th>
    <th id="m1">13</th>
    <th id="n1">14</th>
    <th id="o1">15</th>
    <th id="p1">16</th>
    <th id="q1">17</th>
    <th id="r1">18</th>
    <th id="s1">19</th>
    <th id="t1">20</th>
    <th id="u1">21</th>
    <th id="v1">22</th>
    <th id="w1">23</th>
    <th id="x1">24</th>
    <th id="y1">25</th>
    <th id="z1">26</th>
    <th id="aa1">27</th>
    <th id="ab1">28</th>
    <th id="ac1">29</th>
    <th id="ad1">30</th>
    <th id="ae1">31</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id = "a2" >0</td>
    <td id = "b2" >0</td>
    <td id = "c2" >0</td>
    <td id = "d2" >0</td>
    <td id = "e2" >0</td>
    <td id = "f2" >0</td>
    <td id = "g2" >0</td>
    <td id = "h2" >0</td>
    <td id = "i2" >0</td>
    <td id = "j2" >0</td>
    <td id = "k2" >0</td>
    <td id = "l2" >0</td>
    <td id = "m2" >0</td>
    <td id = "n2" >0</td>
    <td id = "o2" >0</td>
    <td id = "p2" >0</td>
    <td id = "q2" >0</td>
    <td id = "r2" >0</td>
    <td id = "s2" >0</td>
    <td id = "t2" >0</td>
    <td id = "u2" >0</td>
    <td id = "v2" >0</td>
    <td id = "w2" >0</td>
    <td id = "x2" >0</td>
    <td id = "y2" >0</td>
    <td id = "z2" >0</td>
    <td id = "aa2" >0</td>
    <td id = "ab2" >0</td>
    <td id = "ac2" >0</td>
    <td id = "ad2" >0</td>
    <td id = "ae2" >0</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id = "a3" >0</td>
    <td id = "b3" >0</td>
    <td id = "c3" >0</td>
    <td id = "d3" >0</td>
    <td id = "e3" >0</td>
    <td id = "f3" >0</td>
    <td id = "g3" >0</td>
    <td id = "h3" >0</td>
    <td id = "i3" >0</td>
    <td id = "j3" >0</td>
    <td id = "k3" >0</td>
    <td id = "l3" >0</td>
    <td id = "m3" >0</td>
    <td id = "n3" >0</td>
    <td id = "o3" >0</td>
    <td id = "p3" >0</td>
    <td id = "q3" >0</td>
    <td id = "r3" >0</td>
    <td id = "s3" >0</td>
    <td id = "t3" >0</td>
    <td id = "u3" >0</td>
    <td id = "v3" >0</td>
    <td id = "w3" >0</td>
    <td id = "x3" >0</td>
    <td id = "y3" >0</td>
    <td id = "z3" >0</td>
    <td id = "aa3" >0</td>
    <td id = "ab3" >0</td>
    <td id = "ac3" >0</td>
    <td id = "ad3" >0</td>
    <td id = "ae3" >0</td>
  </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You already know how to select the `"a2"` element, so what's stopping you from doing the same to select the `"a1"` element?

Comment: ...and I don't know what you mean by *"sum the number digit by digit"*.

Comment: 1. I want to sum the selected number from drop down + the number of first cell which is one so 1+1 = 2.
2. I mean if the dropdown number is 11 and the cell is 13
it would be (1+1) + (1+3) = 24

Comment: First things first. You should show that you actually selected the values you want to sum. That was left out of the question. To fix this new problem, you could Google for it first, since every beginner ever has run into this same issue. Anyway, the answers below give solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must want to use `parseInt()` to convert your html or text to numbers and be able to sum them.

Here is a working example where I only modified the JS a little:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var month = document.getElementById("drop");
    document.getElementById("a2").innerHTML = parseInt(drop.options[drop.selectedIndex].text) + parseInt(document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th, tr{
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form>
  Number:
  <select id="drop" onchange ="myFunction()">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
    <option>13</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
<table>
    <tr>
  <tr>
    <th id="a1">1</th>
    <th id="b1">2</th>
    <th id="c1">3</th>
    <th id="d1">4</th>
    <th id="e1">5</th>
    <th id="f1">6</th>
    <th id="g1">7</th>
    <th id="h1">8</th>
    <th id="i1">9</th>
    <th id="j1">10</th>
    <th id="k1">11</th>
    <th id="l1">12</th>
    <th id="m1">13</th>
    <th id="n1">14</th>
    <th id="o1">15</th>
    <th id="p1">16</th>
    <th id="q1">17</th>
    <th id="r1">18</th>
    <th id="s1">19</th>
    <th id="t1">20</th>
    <th id="u1">21</th>
    <th id="v1">22</th>
    <th id="w1">23</th>
    <th id="x1">24</th>
    <th id="y1">25</th>
    <th id="z1">26</th>
    <th id="aa1">27</th>
    <th id="ab1">28</th>
    <th id="ac1">29</th>
    <th id="ad1">30</th>
    <th id="ae1">31</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id = "a2" >0</td>
    <td id = "b2" >0</td>
    <td id = "c2" >0</td>
    <td id = "d2" >0</td>
    <td id = "e2" >0</td>
    <td id = "f2" >0</td>
    <td id = "g2" >0</td>
    <td id = "h2" >0</td>
    <td id = "i2" >0</td>
    <td id = "j2" >0</td>
    <td id = "k2" >0</td>
    <td id = "l2" >0</td>
    <td id = "m2" >0</td>
    <td id = "n2" >0</td>
    <td id = "o2" >0</td>
    <td id = "p2" >0</td>
    <td id = "q2" >0</td>
    <td id = "r2" >0</td>
    <td id = "s2" >0</td>
    <td id = "t2" >0</td>
    <td id = "u2" >0</td>
    <td id = "v2" >0</td>
    <td id = "w2" >0</td>
    <td id = "x2" >0</td>
    <td id = "y2" >0</td>
    <td id = "z2" >0</td>
    <td id = "aa2" >0</td>
    <td id = "ab2" >0</td>
    <td id = "ac2" >0</td>
    <td id = "ad2" >0</td>
    <td id = "ae2" >0</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id = "a3" >0</td>
    <td id = "b3" >0</td>
    <td id = "c3" >0</td>
    <td id = "d3" >0</td>
    <td id = "e3" >0</td>
    <td id = "f3" >0</td>
    <td id = "g3" >0</td>
    <td id = "h3" >0</td>
    <td id = "i3" >0</td>
    <td id = "j3" >0</td>
    <td id = "k3" >0</td>
    <td id = "l3" >0</td>
    <td id = "m3" >0</td>
    <td id = "n3" >0</td>
    <td id = "o3" >0</td>
    <td id = "p3" >0</td>
    <td id = "q3" >0</td>
    <td id = "r3" >0</td>
    <td id = "s3" >0</td>
    <td id = "t3" >0</td>
    <td id = "u3" >0</td>
    <td id = "v3" >0</td>
    <td id = "w3" >0</td>
    <td id = "x3" >0</td>
    <td id = "y3" >0</td>
    <td id = "z3" >0</td>
    <td id = "aa3" >0</td>
    <td id = "ab3" >0</td>
    <td id = "ac3" >0</td>
    <td id = "ad3" >0</td>
    <td id = "ae3" >0</td>
  </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is correct function:

```
function myFunction() {
    var month = document.getElementById("drop");
    var a1 = Number(document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML);
    var dropVal = Number(drop.options[drop.selectedIndex].text);
    document.getElementById("a2").innerHTML = dropVal + a1;
}
```